# Lua Acessing table values within nested table

Tags: lua, nested, lua-table

I'm trying to test certain variables on a grid made out of nested tables. However no matter what I try it wont give me the values stored within the variables only the data type or a nil value

```
y = {}
for _y = 0,16 do
    for _x = 0,16 do
        x = {}
        x.x = _x
        x.y = _y
        x.v = flr(rnd(2))

        if x.x < 1 or x.x > 14 then
            x.v = 3
        end


        if x.v == 0 then
            x.v = "."
        elseif x.v ==1 then
            x.v = ","
        else
            x.v = "0"
        end
        add(y,x)
    end
end
```

I've tried accessing the value using

```
print(t[1][3])
```

But this only prints back a nil value, how would I code this to show whats stored within the value within these two tables?

Comment: shouldn't it be `print(y[1].x)`?

Comment: Yes, are you incorrectly using [3] to get at .v?

Answer (score 2):

You have the nesting as follows:

```
y = {x_1, x_2, x_3, ...}
```

where, each of `x_i` is of the form:

```
x = {
  x = p,
  y = q,
  v = r
}
```

so, you will have the indexing for each `x` element as `y[i]`, and each `y[i]` contains 3 attributes:

```
print(y[1].x)
```

will give you `x_1.x`

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a 2-dimensional table, but only create a 1-dimensional one.

Fix your code to look somewhat like this

```
y = {}
for _y=1,16 do
    y[_y] = {}
    for _x=1,16 do
        y[_y][_x]= "your data"
    end
end
```